# DBContext SaveChangesAsync espera y no continua

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo un webapi montado con el patron repository y unidad de trabajo y necesito hacer un guardado asincrono pero no lo consigo.

En mi capa de servicios tengo lo siguiente:

```
List<Task> guardadosAsincronos = new List<Task>();
while (...) {
    ...
    guardadosAsincronos.Add(this.SaveAsync());
    ...
}
for (var i = 0; i < guardadosAsincronos.Count; i++) {
    guardadosAsincronos[i].Wait();
}
```

Cada clase de la capa de servicios extiende de otra base que contiene la siguiente funcion:

```
public async Task<int> SaveAsync() {
    int result = await this._unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Esta llama a la funcion de la clase UnitOfWork:

```
public Task<int> CommitAsync() {
    return this._databaseFactory.Get().CommitAsync();
}
```

y a su vez, esta llama a la del contexto:

```
public virtual Task<int> CommitAsync() {
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
}
```

Cuando hago el primer guardado, se van llamando a las funciones una tras otra pero, al llegar a la funcion del contexto, la ejecución se detiene, por lo que en lugar de un guardado asincrono, se hace uno sincrono y mi bucle principal de la capa de servicio no continua hasta que el guardado finaliza.

Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal para que no se realice el guardado asincrono ???

Comment: Y si pones el `await` dentro de `CommitAsync` en lugar de al llamar al método?

Comment: no entendi muy bien a que te refieres... he probado a poner el await en cada una de las funciones, cada vez en una distinta, y el SaveChangesAsync del contexto siempre acaba bloqueando la ejecución... el problema es que mi while actualiza en torno a 15000 objetos, haciendo el save de 1000 en 1000... por la cantidad de objetos, me interesa que ese while no se bloquee y al final comprobar que todos los guardados han terminado para continuar...

Comment: Yo no suelo trabajar con `entity-framework`, asi que tampoco estoy muy seguro de cual puede ser el problema. Te sugería que probaras `return await base.SaveChangesAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());` en el método `CommitAsync`

Comment: nos cruzamos los comentarios... esa prueba tambien la acabo de hacer y nada, la ejecucion del while siempre se acaba parando...

Comment: Como te digo, no soy experto en entity framework, lo siento. Esperemos que alguien te pueda ayudar :)

Comment: gracias de todos modos @Pikoh... a ver si alguien mas comenta

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el `for` donde ejecutas el método `Wait()`. [Segun la documetacion del metodo Wait()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Espera a que la tarea complete la ejecución.

Lo que claramente da a enteder, que hasta que no se termine la ejecucion de cada hilo, el `Wait` detendra la ejecución y esperara a que termine el método para continuar.

Por ejemplo:

```
 List<Task> ts = new List<Task>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ Thread.Sleep(2000); Console.WriteLine("Ejecutando hilo 1"); }),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ Thread.Sleep(2000); Console.WriteLine("Ejecutando hilo 2"); }),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ Thread.Sleep(2000); Console.WriteLine("Ejecutando hilo 3"); })
};

foreach (var t in ts)
{
    t.Wait();
}
Console.WriteLine("Termino");
```

El resultado de la impresión debería de ser asi para ser asíncrono:

```
Termino
Ejecutando hilo 2
Ejecutando hilo 1
Ejecutando hilo 3
```

Pero en realidad es:

```
Ejecutando hilo 1
Ejecutando hilo 2
Ejecutando hilo 3
Termino
```

Lo que indica que no se esta ejecutando asincronamente del todo ya que se ejecuta segun el orden en que fue creado, lo que no debería ser(al menos no debieria de ser la regla). Mientras que si eliminamos la ejecucion del `Wait()`, se imprime el resultado esperado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, te explico, si miras mis comentarios anteriores, dentro del while voy actualizando 15000 objetos... a cada 1000 les hago un guardado... al final (en el for) tengo que esperar que los 15 savechangesasync que hay en ejecución terminen pues otras funciones acceden a estos datos...

Comment: He visto el hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042791/entity-framework-savechanges-vs-savechangesasync-and-find-vs-findasync donde explican exactamente lo que yo quiero hacer (primera respuesta)... pero a mi se me bloquea al hacer el savechangesasync y segun explican ahi, el bucle principal continua su ejecución... la diferencia es que el solo espera un guardado y yo tendre que esperar mas... de ahi mi bucle for.

Comment: Con solo decir que necesitas esperar a que terminen los SaveChanges para continuar con otro proceso, da a enteder que lo que quieres no es posible. No se puede hacer que un proceso espere a que termine otro y que a la vez sea asincrono a lo demas. Has intentado ejecutar todos los SaveChanges dentro de otro hilo y no uno a uno en un hilo?

Comment: Si pero el contexto no permite multi-hilos actuando sobre el... ya lo intentamos para otros casos y daba errores por todos lados, al final vimos en la documentación que no se puede atacar al contexto con hilos de esa forma... si miras el hilo que te comentaba antes, es exactamente lo que yo necesito... pero a el parece que le funciona y a mi no...

Comment: de todos modos, omitiendo el segundo bucle, el gran problema es que, en teoría, base.SaveChangesAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken()); devería devolver el control a la funcion que lo llama y continuar ejecutandose el while (al menos eso es lo que he visto por ahi) pero a mi se me bloquea ahi la ejecución, como si estuviese llamando a SaveChanges()...